# Python Condensing Code

Tags: python

My code is pretty long and I need help condensing it to make it more convenient. The code I have is suppose to do the set of instructions I commanded it to do on a fluke robot. I am using python. The robot is suppose to do the following code using it sensors. I need help condensing it.

EDIT:

My code:

```
from Myro import *
from Graphics import *
init('/dev/tty.IPRE6-366079-DevB')

def markYellow(pic):
    for pix in getPixels(pic):
        r = getRed(pix)
        g = getGreen(pix)
        b = getBlue(pix)
        if r > 200 and b < 90 and g > 150:
            setRed(pix,255)
            setGreen(pix,255)
            setBlue(pix,255)
        else:
            setRed(pix,0)
            setGreen(pix,0)
            setBlue(pix,0)

def pctMarked(pic):
    totalPixels = 0
    whitePixels = 0
    for pix in getPixels(pic):
        if getRed(pix) == 255:
            whitePixels = whitePixels + 1
        totalPixels = totalPixels + 1
    result = whitePixels / float(totalPixels)
    return result


def findAvgX(pic):
    pixelCount  = 0
    totalXCount = 0
    for pix in getPixels(pic):
        if getRed(pix) == 255:
            x = getX(pix)
            totalXCount = totalXCount + x
            pixelCount = pixelCount + 1
    avgX = totalXCount / float( pixelCount)
    return avgX


def turn():
    findAvgX(pic)
    if wallLocation <= 85:
        turnLeft(1,0.25)
    elif ballLocation >= 170:
        turnRight(1,0.25)


def celebrate():
    move(0.25,1)
    beep(1,800)
    beep(1,1600)
    beep(1,800)
    stop()

def main():
    p = takePicture()
    markYellow(p)
    pctMarked(p)
    while pctMarked(pic) < 0.2: 
        rotate(1,1)
        p = takePicture()
        markYellow(p)
        pctMarked(p)
    turn()
    while getObstacle('center')> 1000: # I'm not sure about the number. We can test it tomorrow
        forward(1,1)
    celebrate()
```

Comment: Can you implement `getRGB` and `setRGB` instead of `getRed`, `setRed`, ...? That way, you could do `r, g, b = getRGB(pix)` and `setRGB(pix, r, g, b)`.

Comment: Your code is not pretty long. In fact, I'd say it's pretty short.

Comment: Unless it's a very focused question about a specific piece of code that you think could be condensed by a python builtin function or something, I think that a question like this (with working code) is probably a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.  I'll vote to close and we'll see if anyone else agrees...

Comment: How come I got a negative for this? And its pretty long for my standard since I am a beginner. It is barely my first month. and @Blender I could , but I do not know how to implement it with out messing up the code .

Comment: @queensmatin: There's a better place to ask this question. Your question *might* get migrated there.

Comment: @Blender I am sorry for that! Where exactly is a good place to ask this question?

Comment: @mgilson I apologize for that! Is there a way to migrate this question there?

Comment: @queensmatin: Nobody really knows. There's [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but if the question actually needs to move, it will move on its own.

Comment: @Blender, hey that was my idea :p

Comment: "its pretty long for my standard since I am a beginner" and "I could , but I do not know how to implement it with out messing up the code". How can a beginner have a standard? If you don't know how to refactor, then you have a much bigger problem than just subjective code compactness... (no offense!)

Comment: Considering how good the first answer is to this question, I'd say this was a very good newbie question about how to make his python code more readable.  To close it as off topic seems rude.

Comment: @Mark0978 I agree! Programmers always shred me into pieces here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# helper functions
def getRGB(pix):
    return getRed(pix), getGreen(pix), getBlue(pix)

def setRGB(pix, r, g, b):
    setRed(pix,r)
    setGreen(pix,g)
    setBlue(pix,b)

def markYellow(pic):
    for pix in getPixels(pic):
        r, g, b = getRGB(pix)
        if r > 200 and b < 90 and g > 150:
            setRGB(pix, 255, 255, 255) 
        else:
            setRGB(pix, 0, 0, 0)

def pctMarked(pic):
    # is there a more direct way to get the totalPixels?
    # totalPixels = len(pic) # perhaps?
    totalPixels = sum(1 for pix in getPixels(pic))
    whitePixels = sum(getRGB(pix) == (255, 255, 255) for pix in getPixels(pic))
    return whitePixels / float(totalPixels)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Gnibbler!! I will review this code and see if it works.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you but I have trouble using codes and mine. I edited my post above with my whole code. You think you can take a look at it because when I tried using your code, it doesnt work properly. I am assuming since I left out the other parts of my codes.

Answer (score 1):

This implementation works on the idea that you have an `ARGB` pixel, if you have an `RGB` pixel replace:

`0xFFFFFFFF` with `0xFFFFFF`

What I am doing is this:

```
pixel = A R G B
A = 2 bytes
R = 2 bytes
G = 2 bytes
B = 2 bytes
```

so in hex that is:

```
pixel = 0xFF000000; # black
pixel = 0xFFFFFFFF; # white
```

`A` has to be `FF` (255) to have no transparency.

I should mention that I make an assumption with this code, that is, a pixel is in the form of a 32bit Integer.

---

```
def markYellow(pic):
    for pix in getPixels(pic):
        if getRed(pix) > 200 and getBlue(pix) < 90 and getGreen(pix) > 150:
            pix = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        else:
            pix = 0xFF000000;

def pctMarked(pic):
    totalPixels = 0
    whitePixels = 0
    for pix in getPixels(pic):
        if pix == 0xFFFFFFFF:
            whitePixels += 1
        totalPixels += 1
    return whitePixels / float(totalPixels)
```

---

couple of comments:
your `pcMarked` was only looking at red to find white, this meant it will pick up ALL fully red colours.
your `markyellow` function is making the pixel white instead of yellow.

Comment: There is no way of knowing from the code posted if `pix` is a hex value.  It could be another class instance with getters and setters.

Comment: @ktodisco, maybe they have the same homework

Comment: Is it possible to get the totalPixels directly using `len()` or multiplying the width by the height or something?

Comment: pix is a pixel, hence the `getpixels` which means it can be used as a hex value... if not then `getPixels` is a misleading function call.

Comment: @gnibbler by the looks of things `getpixels` returns an enumerable type filled with pixels, it would be reasonable to assume you can use `len()` on that enumberable, yes.

Comment: Thank you serdalis! I dont quite understand your comments but I will take a look at your code and see if it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @queensmatin look up a programming language called `processing`, and look up the tutorials for it, you'll find them amazingly useful for image editing :)